# Trying to remove program flmsg and am getting message "unable to locate package"

Tags: 18.04

Running Ubuntu 18.04 Dell Latitude E6420 8 GB memory

The program flmsg shows when I list the directory, as shown below:

```
howard@dell-Latitude-E6420:~/Ham radio programs/FLDIGI$ ls
 flamp-2.2.04.tar.gz
 fldigi-4.1.00
 fldigi-4.1.00.tar.gz
 flmsg-4.0.8
 flmsg-4.0.8.tar.gz
 flrig-1.3.42
 flrig-1.3.42.tar.gz
```

When I do a `sudo apt remove flmsg-4.0.8` it returns:

```
howard@dell-Latitude-E6420:~/Ham radio programs/FLDIGI$ sudo apt remove flmsg-4.0.8
[sudo] password for howard: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package flmsg-4.0.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'flmsg-4.0.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'flmsg-4.0.8'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls` is a command that lists the contents of the directory. From your outputs it seems that the `flmsg-4.0.8` is merely a file that exists in ***~/Ham radio programs/FLDIGI/*** folder not an APT package that is installed. So, deleting those files might help. You can delete that files using some file manager like Nautilus or by running `rm -r flmsg*` in terminal.